# Powershell alternative to curl when calling Jenkins API

Tags: powershell, api, rest, jenkins, curl

I would like to find a PowerShell alternative to curl most specific when calling jenkins api and getting a return output.

```
curl --silent -k https://jenkins:8443/job/myjob/buildwithParameters -i
```

The curl parameter `-i` will return the queue number in the output.
With the queue item I can easily query again the API and get the results of the specific job.

Location: https://jenkinsserver:8443/queue/item/**317**/

I can successfully wrap curl into a PowerShell script/function however I would like to eliminate this dependency.

```
PS C:\> curl.exe --silent -k https://jenkinsserver:8443/job/MyJOB/buildWithParameters --user myuser:****myapitoken****** --data ComputerName=XYZ003 --data State=start --data --data ve
rbosity=high -i
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Wed, 02 Dec 2020 02:52:01 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Location: https://jenkinsserver:8443/queue/item/317/
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(9.4.30.v20200611)

PS C:\>
```

Comment: have you tried searching for that yet? [*grin*] take a look at `Get-Alias curl` for one idea. also, the version of the cmdlet you will see has been _seriously_ improved in ps7+.

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest or Invoke-RestMethod are the two cmdlets that could be used, however I am looking on how to get an output when calling the Jenkins API, "curl.exe -i ", basically how can I get the same behavior and that the "-i " in curl but  same functionality using only PowerShell.

Comment: according to the `curl` man page, the `-i, --include` option says to `Include the HTTP response headers in the output`. according to the results of searching for `Invoke-RestMethod include response headers`, you cannot get that from `I-RM`. however, you CAN get it from `Invoke-WebRequest`. there is some detailed info here >>> Invoke-RestMethod Response Headers? : PowerShell — https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/4smvtk/invokerestmethod_response_headers/